# Is it faster to initialize smtp once or initialize it every time you use it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, gmail, smtplib

As the title says, my question is: is it faster to initialize smtp once and send a lot of emails using that one instance or is it better to initialize it every time you use it?  or it completely doesnt matter? I am using python.

For example. Is it faster to do this

```
def email():

    import smtplib 

    sender_email_id = 'email here'
    sender_email_id_password = 'password here'
    message = "message here"
    
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
    s.starttls() 
    s.login("sender_email_id", "sender_email_id_password") 
    s.sendmail("sender_email_id", "receiver_email_id", message) 
    s.quit() 

for i in range(10):
    email()
```

or to do this?

```
import smtplib 

sender_email_id = 'email here'
sender_email_id_password = 'password here'
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
s.starttls() 
s.login("sender_email_id", "sender_email_id_password") 

def email(message):

    s.sendmail(sender_email_id, "to_someone@email.com", message) 
   

for i in range(10):
    email(message)

s.quit()
```

Comment: At very least you should limit number of messages submitted via single SMTP connection (e.g. 50). Many SMTP servers impose limits on it as antispam/antubulk prevention.

Answer (score 0):

Based from other frameworks and common practice, I think you should register your SMTP configuration once in separated config file and re-use that information to execute the mail sending many times.

Please note that opening and closing SMTP connection everytime you send an email will consume more resource and time due to open and close (I/O) transmission between your system and SMTP server.

So, initialize once and re-use the object should be faster and more efficient.